# How to return different types of object from a method in java?

Tags: java, class, object, casting

I want to ask you how a single method can return different types of objects in java?

lets say we have a class "a". class a is parent class of classes "b" and "c".
lets say we have an array list defined as:

```
java.util.ArrayList<a> list;
```

so this list can contain objects of class a, class b and class c.
lets say we create one object of class b, and one object of class c, and we add them to list.

now, i want to create a method like this:

```
public ? get_element(boolean first)
{
    if (first)
    {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    else
    {
        return list.get(1);
    }
}
```

my problem is, that i do not know what to put at the place of "?" in this method.
if i put "a", so, "public a get_element", when element is returned it is always of type "a", no matter if element was originally of type "b" or "c" when it was added.

but i want that element returned is of type of element added.
so, if i add element of type "b" at index 0 of the list, and element of type "c" at index 1, i wish when i call get_element method, that if i provide parameter equal to "false", that returned element is of type "c", and if i provide true when i call it, that returned element is of type b.

of course, i can cast returned element to the type i wish. but this is just simple example i wrote, but i for real have much more complex situation. i have about 10 classes which all extend one class, and array list which can contain any of those 11 types of objects, and they can be arranged in any way, so i can not know what type of element is at which position, unless i create a code which will try to cast to all types, one by one until it finds the one to which it can cast.

but i want to know, is there some kind of more easy way to do so?

to simplify my question, i wrote this .java file:

```
public class test
{
    public static class a{}
    public static class b extends a{}
    public static class c extends a{}
    public static java.util.ArrayList<a> list = new java.util.ArrayList<a>(2);
    static
    {
        b first_object = new b();
        c second_object = new c();
        list.add(first_object);
        list.add(second_object);
        b first_returned_object = get_element(true);
        c second_returned_object = get_element(false);
    }
    public static ? get_element(boolean first)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            return list.get(0);
        }
        else
        {
            return list.get(1);
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is that i do not know what to put before "get_element" in get element method.

what should i put in order that i can save object of type b in "first_returned_object", and object of type c in "second_returned_object"?

of course, this is just example, i would not use these classes, because they are useless, but i wrote this to make my question as simple as possible.

my real classes where i have this kind of problem have 5000+ lines, so i could not include those here, so i wrote the simplest possible version which demonstrates my problem.

any suggestions?

thanx.

post scriptum:
to caps lock haters: your hate is bidirectional here. ;)

Comment: `public a get_element(boolean first)` program to the *interface*.

Comment: Polymorphic returns (and polymorphic collections) are not supported in Java without explicit casts.  If your array list is declared to contain type `A` it can contain elements that are subtypes of `A` but you cannot write a method that will return the actual type, only references of type `A` which you have to cast to `B` or `C` if you need to use methods or public members that appear only on `B` or `C`.

Comment: Just a note for any future questions, this site is for professionals. Please use the shift key when appropriate.

Comment: If it's necessary for you to know the concrete type of an object, your class structure is flawed. You may want to redesign it using [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Comment: Return `a`. It's the only thing that makes any sense. Your client code doesn't need to know if the object is s subclass of `a` and should not care, because a `b` *is a* `a`. See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Jim Garrison, hello, and thanx for your comment. i did not know about this, i thought this might be possible. I am programming in java for last year, but newer came across this situation when i need a method which should return multiple types of objects until now. so i did not know this is not possible. well, if it is not, then i am condemned to finding the type of returned object and than casting it. anyway, thanx for clarifying me that.

Comment: hay Bohemian, yea, i know that. i do return "a", but, in my real code, where there are methods in classes such as "b" and "c", i need to execute some method in that class, which is not available if object is returned as a. i was looking to find a way to return object of type b or c depending on what was the type of object when it was added.

Comment: @SYOBSYOT can you send the index number of arraylist as argument instead of `boolean`? Like for first element `0`, second element `1` etc.

Comment: hay Skeweverything,
of course. this method `public static ? get_element(boolean first)` is just here for example, to make it as simple as possible. it can be `public static ? get_element(int index)`. this is actually the case in my real code, but this still does not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Generics to some what make the return type dynamic.

Try this one:

```
public static <Type> Type get_element(int index)
{
    String s = list.get(index).getClass().toString(); // returns "class class_name"
    String[] split = s.split(" ");
    Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(split[1]); // You need "class_name"

    return (Type) theClass.cast(list.get(index));
}
```

or simply:

```
public static <Type> Type get_element(int index)
{
    return (Type) list.get(index);
}
```

Comment: hay Skreweverything,
thank you for your reply.
actually, although i am programming in java for about a year now, i newer used generics. i actually do not even know what those are, but, i will look it up in java documentation right away.

anyway, about your post, well, thank you, a lot. this really does work!
if i replace my get_element method with yours, i do not have to cast returned object anymore.
thank you, i will look up your example, and documentation about generics, learn how to use it, and implement it in my real code.

thanx, this is only useful answer here. :)